# The Categories $\mathrm{Set}\times\mathrm{Set}$ and $\mathrm{Set}+\mathrm{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I'm thinking about the following problem. In $\mathrm{Cat}$ I can form the product $\mathrm{Set}\times\mathrm{Set}$. Elements are tuples, say $(A,X)$. I think that inner products and coproducts are just formed pairwise, i.e. $(A,X)\times(B,Y)=(A\times B,X\times Y)$ and $(A,X)+(B,Y)=(A+B,X+Y)$. On the other hand there is the coproduct $\mathrm{Set}+\mathrm{Set}$. Elements are cotuples like $\langle A,X\rangle$ (is there maybe another more common notion?) or in other words a disjoint union of this two sets. I think, but I'm not sure about it, that $\langle A,X\rangle \times \langle B,Y\rangle = \langle A\times B,X\times Y\rangle $ and $\langle A,X\rangle + \langle B,Y\rangle = \langle A+ B,X+Y\rangle$. Is the internal structure of this two categories absolutely the same? So it doesn't matter whether I built tuples of sets or disjoint unions?  Are they isomorphic? Or is there different behaviour?

Comment: Your description of $\mathbf{Set} + \mathbf{Set}$ is incorrect. For instance, the objects are pairs $(i, X)$, where $i \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ and $X$ is a set.

Comment: So what's the product and coproduct in Set+Set then? Does $(i,X)\times (i,Y)=(i,X\times Y)$ and $(i,X)+(i,Y)=(i,X+Y)$ for $i=0,1$ hold?

Comment: What makes you say that it has products or coproducts? It does not.

Comment: I didn't know it has not. Is there an easy way to see this? Or do you know some piece of literature about it?

Comment: In general, in a coproduct of two categories, two objects in different summands cannot be connected by morphisms - even not via zig zags, since the morphisms don't leave the individual categories. In particular, these object have no product or coproduct.